# Arduino WebSocketClient Sec-WebSocket-Key Error

Tags: websocket, arduino

I built a WebSocket server using [WebSocket-Node](https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node) and the client is an Arduino with an Ethernet shield using the library [WebsocketClient](https://github.com/krohling/ArduinoWebsocketClient) from krohling.

The first issue I had was that even the example from the WebsocketClient library didn't return a response from the echo.websocket.org server.

Since the Arduino's Serial monitor didn't give me errors, I added a Serial.print on the handshake section of the library's code to debug the error and I got the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Kaazing Gateway
Date: Tue, 07 May 2013 05:11:21 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ArduinoWebSocketClient
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-websocket-extensions
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-websocket-version
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-websocket-protocol
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 63
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Then, I tested it with the WebSocket-Node server I created and got the following on the Serial monitor:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: close
X-WebSocket-Reject-Reason: Client must provide a value for Sec-WebSocket-Key.
```

Am I doing something wrong or does the WebsocketClient library need to be updated?

I haven't been lucky to find a better/newer Arduino Websocket client library. Does anyone know about one I could use?

Thanks a lot!